# How parse JSON into ListView

Tags: android, json, algorithm, listview

How parse JSON from server or website into `ListView` in Android Studio>

For example parse this JSON file

```
{
   "courses":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "course":"Русский язык"
      },
      {
        "id":2,
         "course":"English language"
      },
      {
        "id":3,
         "course":"Spanish language"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1) Create a list of objects of id, course

```
try {
    // Convert the String to JSON
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("courses");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = jObject.getString("id");
        String course = jObject.getString("course");
        yourList.add(new Course(id, course))

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Some JSON error occurred" + e.getMessage());
}
```

2) Write an adapter to get the list converted to ListView

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      // override other abstract methods here

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
          if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
          }

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.course))
                  .setText(getItem(position));
          return convertView;
      }
  }
```

Get help from [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: Thank parse work nice but when I create new adapter my application take error .